# Formates (AVI, MPG, FLV, WMV) support issue in ExoPlayer-Android

Tags: android, exoplayer, codec, flv, avi

Hay, I'm developing a video player in Android Kotlin using ExoPlayer. All works fine except some video formats ( AVI, MPG, FLV, WMV). Is there some workaround of making a decoder or codecs ,that can play these formats? or something else to play these formats in my player.

I tried converting video formats with FFmpeg but it took so much time to convert a video. so I am trying to make a decoder or any codec to play these kind of formats. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using FFmpeg is the right choice, however, you don't need to convert a file. 
Instead, you should use ExoPlayer Fmpeg extension to play media files: 
https://github.com/androidx/media/tree/release/libraries/decoder_ffmpeg

There is a modification that supports video files: 
https://github.com/AhmedHumk/ffmpegVideoDecoder 
and 
https://github.com/anilbeesetti/nextlib

Comment: i am using this https://github.com/anilbeesetti/nextlib & it is already using decoder_ffmpeg, but still the mentioned formats are not playing. can you guide me some more if i am missing something. or is there any thing to add in nextlib player to play these formats.

Comment: hey, @SyedMustafeez have you found any solution , since i am facing the same issue.